# How can I change the class of a button with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code:

```
var image = button.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
if (isEnabled) {
    image.style.color = "#BBB"
else {
    image.style.color = "#AAA"
```

Can someone give me some advice on how instead of directly setting a color that I could set the button to have a 3rd class of enabled and then later set it to have a 3rd class of disabled?

Note that my button currently has classes like this:

```
class="fa fa-bold"
class="fa fa-arrow"
```

etc.

So I would need the first two classes to be unchanged. Then I need to be able to set to like this:

```
class="fa fa-bold enabled"
class="fa fa-bold disabled"
class="fa fa-bold enabled"
```

etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

To add new class `myClass` to image, use `add()`:

> Adds a class to an element's list of classes. If class already exists in the element's list of classes, it will not add the class again.

```
image.classList.add('myClass')
```

To remove class, use `remove()`

> Removes a class from an element's list of classes in a safe manner. Errors are not thrown If the class does not exist.

```
image.classList.remove('myClass')
```

To `toggle` class, use `toggle()`

> If the name exists within the element's classList, it will be removed. If name does not exist, it will be added.

```
image.classList.toggle('myClass') // If exists, remove, if not add
```

To check if element has class, use `contains()`

> Checks if an element's list of classes contains a specific class .

```
if (image.classList.contains('myClass')) {
    alert('HasClass myClass');
} else {
    alert('Dont have class');
}
```

**CSS**

```
.myClass {
    color: #bbb;
}
```

Comment: Note: `.classList` requires IE10 or greater.

Comment: In my case I am not sure which classes the button has so should I first remove both enabled and disabled and then just add the one? Can you give an example like this for my particular code?  thanks

Comment: .ie10 or greater is okay for my needs :-)

Comment: If you are not sure you can remove all classes you don't and add those you need.

Comment: @jfriend00 The `MDN` doc also provide polyfills for browsers that don't support these properties

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty big polyfill.  Not sure I'd want to lug that around in my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using a library like jQuery that has className functionality built in and you want browser support from older browsers, then you can use your own little functions to add or remove a class name from a DOM object without disturbing the other class names like this:

```
function addClass(elem, cls) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, cls)) {
        var oldCls = elem.className;
        if (oldCls) {
            oldCls += " ";
        }
        elem.className = oldCls + cls;
    }
}

function removeClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    elem.className = str.replace(" " + cls + " ", " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

function hasClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    var testCls = " " + cls + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(testCls) !== -1) ;
}

removeClass(image, "enabled");
addClass(image, "disabled");
```

Comment: I'd add an internal check in the `addFunction` wether the class exists. Otherwise something like `myClass myClass` is possible.

Comment: @AMartinNo1 - I updated with a little more capable version that checks if the cls already exists.  I was trying to keep the answer as simple as possible (not drag in too much other code), but I see your point.